# Can one design a class containing default values for template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

One can provide default values for template classes like this:

```
template<class T = int>
class Foo 
{ /* ... some implementation details ... */ };
```

Is it possible to provide the default value "int" thanks to another class?
I would like to design an object "Parameters" which contains some default values for specific template classes. These default values should be read from an input configuration file. From a syntaxic viewpoint, it should look like this:

```
template<class T = Parameters::FooDefaultValue>
class Foo 
{ /* ... some implementation details ... */ };
```

However, I don't know if it is possible with some typdef or template alias, or any other approach.

Do you know if something like this is possible?
Otherwise, do you know another solution to my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: As long `Parameters::FooDefaultValue` provides a typedef or type, it's possible yes.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong?  Did you try exactly what you posted?  If so, what went wrong?

Comment: When you say "These default values should be read from an input configuration file", do you mean at runtime? That's not possible because template parameters are assigned at compile time.

Comment: I have tried to declare a default value, e.g. template<class T=int> class Foo { /* .... */ }, and it worked. However, I did not manage to replace "int" by a typedef declared in another class. Maybe I need to put the keyword "typename" somewhere but I do not know where.

Comment: The configuration file may be read at compile time: that's not a problem for me. For example, it could be a Make or CMake configuration file activating some macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a type to a value, you can however have value template arguments, something like e.g.

```
template<typename T = int, int DefaultValue = Parameters::FooDefaultValue>
class Foo
{
    ...
};
```

This of course requires that `Parameters::FooDefaultValue` is a compile-time constant or `constexpr`.

Comment: Ok, I just want to do the same thing as you do for the first template parameter, but I want "int" to come from an external class; it could be a typedef or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Template arguments (be they types or values) *must* be known at compile time, so they cannot be read from a configuration file at runtime.

Comment: It can be done at compile time with some macros. It's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) or the boost::enable_if equivalent if you don't have C++11. I'm thinking something like this; this won't compile, but is a rough outline, maybe?:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_of_type<T,Parameters>::value, Parameters::FooDefaultValue>::type 
    foo1(T t) 
{
    std::cout << "foo1: float\n";
    return t;
}
```

Note: is_of_type::value is a non-standard made up thing.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark! I do not know this feature. I need to understand it to see if it suits my needs. I come back later. ;-)